# Python or bash script: if pattern in lines between two identical markers, remove lines and first marker

Tags: python, bash, design-patterns, marker, lines

As a beginner, I'm trying to solve the following problem (bash or python script):

the file (~50G!):

```
marker
xxx
xxx
xxx
pattern
marker
xxx
xxx
xxx
marker
xxx
xxx
xxx
pattern
```

I would like to find a way to remove the lines between two `markers` + the first `marker`, but not the last occurrence of the `marker` IF no `pattern` can be found throughout the lines.

Wanted result:

```
marker
xxx
xxx
xxx
pattern
[empty!]
marker
xxx
xxx
xxx
pattern
```

I tried to solve it with regex or awk (that's a very shy beginning)

```
awk '/marker/{f=1} f; /marker/{f=1}' file
```

but I'm having a hardtime understanding how to implement that in a function that would solve the entire problem. It would make me very happy if someone could help me with that!

Cheers

Comment: Do you want the `empty` line?

Comment: @user3483203 without! Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do it in python. Treat `marker` as a separator, then remove anything from the text snippets between that don't contain `pattern`

```
f = open('markerfile.txt','r')

lines = f.read().split('marker\n')
lines = [entry for entry in lines if 'pattern' in entry or not entry]
print 'marker\n'.join(lines)
```

Edit: the `or not entry` bit in the list comprehension just handles the case where `marker` is the first line in the file.

Edit 2: Here's a streaming version (better suited for large files.) It uses `islice` from `itertools` to get `n` lines of the file at a time. The rest of the algorithm is more or less the same.

```
from itertools import islice

f = open('markerfile.txt','r')
fout = open('markersout.txt','w')

n=5
while True:
    next_n_lines = ''.join(list(islice(f, n)))
    if not next_n_lines:
        break
    lines = next_n_lines.split('marker\n')
    lines = [entry for entry in lines if 'pattern' in entry or not entry]
    print >> fout, 'marker\n'.join(lines).strip()

f.close()
fout.close()
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to adapt it from what you wrote.

Comment: You didn't mention that it was 50G before -- you'll want a streaming option instead that reads and writes at the same time.

Comment: Updated my answer to include a streaming version.

Comment: No I didn't; thought it might not be relevant but it is! Thank you!